# Can I say there is a strong correlation between 2 variables if the correlation is negative

Tags: correlation

A data science test support that a correlation of `0.63` can be said as a stronger correlation than a correlation of `-0.85` due to the negative sign.

I was not able to find any documentation supporting the claim.
Is it correct?

Comment: Maybe the best solution might look like a dodge: rather than using a vague nonquantitative term like "stronger," why not use a specific term like "more positive"?

Comment: What test said this?

Comment: A data science certification for a big cloud solution provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strength means absolute value of correlation. Sign means positive or negative.

A correlation of $-0.85$ is stronger than one of $0.63$ and being negative is just a different fact.

Consider that the same logic would require you to say that a correlation of $0.0\ +$ any very small positive number you name is stronger than one of $-1$, which is not something I ever have seen argued, or something compatible with discussions of strength in principle or in practice.